# How to Print String object Line by Line

Tags: java, xml, string, file, filereader

I have the following code to convert text file to xml.:-

**

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
  new ToXML().doit();
}

public void doit () {
try{
  in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/sample.txt"));
  out = new StreamResult("D:/data.xml");
  initXML();
  String str;   
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
  {  
     process(str);
  }
  in.close();
  writeXML();
}
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

public void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException{
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
DOMImplementation impl = builder.getDOMImplementation();
xmldoc = impl.createDocument(null, "AIRLINE_INFO", null);
root = xmldoc.getDocumentElement();
}

public void process(String s) {
String elements = s;
Element e1 = xmldoc.createElement("Supplier_Name");
Node  n1 = xmldoc.createTextNode(elements);
e1.appendChild(n1);

Element e2 = xmldoc.createElement("E-Mail_Address");
Node  n2 = xmldoc.createTextNode(elements);
e2.appendChild(n2);

e0.appendChild(e1);
e0.appendChild(e2);
root.appendChild(e0);
}

public void writeXML() throws TransformerConfigurationException,
      TransformerException {
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmldoc);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,"ISO-8859-1");
transformer.setOutputProperty
   ("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

transformer.transform(domSource, out);

}
}
```

**

The output which is Expected is:
**

```
<AIRLINE_INFO> 
<AIRTICKET> 
<Supplier_Name>SpiceJet Ltd, 319, Udyog Vihar, Phase IV, Gurgaon - 122016 Haryana, India</Supplier_Name> 
<E-Mail_Address>E-Mail: custrelations@spicejet.com</E-Mail_Address> 
</AIRTICKET> 
</AIRLINE_INFO>
```

**

But Currently While Excuting the code i am getting the following output

**

```
<AIRLINE_INFO> 
<AIRTICKET> 
<Supplier_Name>SpiceJet Ltd, 319, Udyog Vihar, Phase IV, Gurgaon - 122016 Haryana, India</Supplier_Name> 
<E-Mail_Address>SpiceJet Ltd, 319, Udyog Vihar, Phase IV, Gurgaon - 122016 Haryana, India</E-Mail_Address> 
</AIRTICKET> 
<AIRTICKET> 
<Supplier_Name>E-Mail: custrelations@spicejet.com</Supplier_Name> 
<E-Mail_Address>E-Mail: custrelations@spicejet.com</E-Mail_Address> 
</AIRTICKET>
</AIRLINE_INFO>
```

**

Please help how can i break the object in order to achieve the Expected output.

Comment: the text file contains only two line mentioned in the xml tags. Thank you

Comment: Look closely at your method `public void process(String s) {` and what it does and explain to me why you expect anything else from your output.

Comment: In oprder to avoid the complexity i have used ** public void process(String s) { ** . here i am passing the String object and creating the node. Hope that help @GermannArlington

Comment: I can see what you wanted it to do, but that is **not** what it does, and I asked you to explain what it actually does  (i.e. to read your code and follow it). Good luck.

Comment: It reads the text file i.e. sample.txt and converting the content to .xml(data.xml)

Comment: Once again - that is what you want to do, but that is **not** what you code does.

Comment: Henry (in his answer) actually pointed directly at the code in error and you still can't see it.

Comment: That is the what the code does. For your reference i have shared the Output also that i am getting while executing the code, But the expected output is different.Output mentioned under **But Currently While Excuting the code i am getting the following output** is exactly the same that i am getting.

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to ask yourself (and look at your code) **why** you get the same information in both `<Supplier_Name>` **and** `<E-Mail_Address>` tags? Look at your code and find out why. I can see why it is happening, Henry can see it too, so you should be able to see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You use two times the same string for the text nodes here:

```
String elements = s;
Element e1 = xmldoc.createElement("Supplier_Name");
Node  n1 = xmldoc.createTextNode(elements);
e1.appendChild(n1);

Element e2 = xmldoc.createElement("E-Mail_Address");
Node  n2 = xmldoc.createTextNode(elements);
e2.appendChild(n2);
```

To fix that, you need to read two lines, and then create one air ticket node with that information.

Comment: I am able to read two line one after another, but is there any way to print it line by line with String object. @Henry